# How to test for Mobile Safari that supports upload other than version string?

Tags: file-upload, mobile-safari, ios6, browser-detection, file-io

iOS 6 now supports uploading images via the `<input type='file'>` tag.

Is there any way to check for this support other than getting the user agent and checking whether the Safari version is 6.0 or greater?  That seems kinda kludgy and prone to breaking if the user agent changes in the future.  Also I'm not sure how it would work if users are using alternate browsers.

Answer (score 1):

On my second generation iPod Touch (iOS 4.2.1), the following line of jQuery code evaluates as `true` in both Safari and Atomic Web Browser Lite and `false` in Opera Mini (since Opera Mini supports file uploads). On iPhone Simulator (iOS 6.0), it also evaluates as `false`.

```
$('#selector').prop('disabled')
```